# How to combine multiple DataTables in one DataTable.?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datatable, dataset

I am using Microsoft Access database (Please don’t suggest me to use some other database since I donot have that choice in this particular situation). Since Access Database Table cannot have more than 255 columns, I am using vertical database partition technique where I have splitted informations into 5 different tables. Each table has 100 columns, and first column is primary key. (Please donot suggest me Database Normalization here). Now I need to read data from these five tables so that I can export it into Excel file.

In other to achieve this I have done the following steps, but could not figure out how to combine multiple tables.

1. I am reading each of these Table and putting into separate DataTable into the same DataSet. 
   (Since I am using Access database I cannot select all columns from all tables)
2. I have declared Relationship on these five tables
3. Now I need to combine these DataTables into one DataTable. This means I will have total of 496 columns. I am eliminating primary keys from 4 tables since it is the same information.
   How do I do this?

   ```
   Dim conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
   Conn ="Connection string stuff goes"

   Dim FinalDS As New DataSet
   Dim DataSet1 As New DataSet
   Dim DataSet2 As New DataSet

   SQLstr1 = "SELECT * FROM Table1"
   SQLstr2 = "SELECT * FROM Table2"
   SQLstr3 = "SELECT * FROM Table3"
   SQLstr4 = "SELECT * FROM Table4"
   SQLstr5 = "SELECT * FROM Table5"

   Dim DA1 As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(SQLstr1, cn)
   Dim DA2 As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(SQLstr2, cn)
   Dim DA3 As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(SQLstr3, cn)
   Dim DA4 As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(SQLstr4, cn)
   Dim DA5 As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(SQLstr5, cn)

   Try
      DA1.Fill(FinalDS, "Tl")
      DA2.Fill(FinalDS, "T2")
      DA3.Fill(FinalDS, "T3")
      DA4.Fill(FinalDS, "T4")
      DA5.Fill(FinalDS, "T5")

      Dim DataRelation1 As New DataRelation("R1", _
                       FinalDS.Tables("T1").Columns("ID"), _
                       FinalDS.Tables("T2").Columns("ID"))


      Dim DataRelation2 As New DataRelation("R2", _
                       FinalDS.Tables("T2").Columns("ID"), _
                       FinalDS.Tables("T3").Columns("ID"))

      Dim DataRelation3 As New DataRelation("R3", _
                       FinalDS.Tables("T3").Columns("ID"), _
                       FinalDS.Tables("T4").Columns("ID"))

      Dim DataRelation4 As New DataRelation("R4", _
                       FinalDS.Tables("T4").Columns("ID"), _
                       FinalDS.Tables("T5").Columns("ID"))


      FinalDS.Relations.Add(DataRelation1)
      FinalDS.Relations.Add(DataRelation2)
      FinalDS.Relations.Add(DataRelation3)
      FinalDS.Relations.Add(DataRelation4)
      FinalDS.Relations.Add(DataRelation5)


     'Here I need to combine all these five DataTables into one DataTable
     'So that I can use Export it to excel from that one Final DataTable instead of  reading data from five different DataTables.

      'My Exporting to excel logies goes here which simply supporse to reads data from final DataTable which has 496 columns.

   Catch ex As Exception
       MsgBox(ex.Message)
   End Try
   ```

Comment: @HansUp, yes you are right, I was curious and tested with 300 fields joined. Get exception 'Too many fields defined' - Removed my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would't bother with the DataRelations and would just use the [Merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.merge.aspx) method.  Then hack out the rest like so...

```
    'Make all of the DataTables have the same columns.
    For Each dtPrepForMerge As DataTable In FinalDS.Tables

        For Each dtColumnsToGrab As DataTable In FinalDS.Tables

            For Each dc As DataColumn In dtColumnsToGrab.Columns

                'Don't duplicate columns.
                If dtPrepForMerge.Columns(dc.ColumnName) Is Nothing Then

                    dtPrepForMerge.Columns.Add(New DataColumn(dc.ColumnName, dc.DataType))

                End If

            Next

        Next

    Next

    'Now you can merge all of the tables together.
    'The order of the columns don't have to be the same between the tables.
    For intTableMergeCursor As Integer = 1 To (FinalDS.Tables.Count - 1)

        FinalDS.Tables(0).Merge(FinalDS.Tables(intTableMergeCursor))

    Next

    'Clone a new table that will hold your final results.
    Dim dtFinalResult As DataTable = FinalDS.Tables(0).Clone()

    'Sort the rows of your merged table by ID.
    Dim arrSortedDataRows As DataRow() = FinalDS.Tables(0).Select("id > 0", "id")

    Dim intLastID As Integer = CInt(arrSortedDataRows(0).Item("id"))

    Dim drMergedRow As DataRow = dtFinalResult.NewRow()

    For Each dr As DataRow In arrSortedDataRows

        'New ID?
        If CInt(dr.Item("id")) <> intLastID Then

            intLastID = CInt(dr.Item("id"))

            dtFinalResult.Rows.Add(drMergedRow)

            drMergedRow = dtFinalResult.NewRow()

        End If

        For intColumnCursor As Integer = 0 To (dtFinalResult.Columns.Count - 1)

            'Don't overwrite values.
            If Not dr.Item(intColumnCursor) Is DBNull.Value Then

                drMergedRow.Item(intColumnCursor) = dr.Item(intColumnCursor)

            End If

        Next

    Next

    dtFinalResult.Rows.Add(drMergedRow)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use datatable.columns.add - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfx3s9wd.aspx#Y166

Below is untested code, may not compile, but the idea is to loop through all datatables and add the columns to one big datatable.

```
Dim HugeDT as new datatable

For dt as datatable in FinalDS.DataTables
    For col as datacolumn in dt.Columns
        HugeDT.columns.add (col)
    Next
    'Run a loop on rows of each datatable to copy over the rows.
    'Remember to correlate the recordpointer correctly for each iteration
Next
```

Comment: A slight improvement would be to use HugeDT.Columns.AddRange(dt.Columns), but the real problem is the data copying here. We don't know how many record need to be copied 5 times.

Comment: If there is one to one relationship between all the tables, it should be linear. I dont have access to an editor now to try something out, hence could not post any related code.